# Calling a class object created by another class that doesn't have a name

Tags: c++, class

I have a class that creates objects of another class, FE:

```
University uni1("University 1");

uni1.createFaculty("Faculty 1");
```

Now I want to call the faculty created to use its functions but I don't know how to...

If by any means this can be found by searching, then forgive me, I didn't know how to phrase  it.

Faculties are stored in a set inside University class.

Comment: Where is the faculty object supposed to be stored?

Comment: In a set of faculties. Class university has it in its private.

Comment: can you give us the class declaration of `University` with it's variables and methods?

Answer (score 2):

You need to see what `University::createFaculty` returns, and use that return value to assign to something:

```
Something x = uni1.createFaculty("hello");
```

where I would guess `Something` is `Faculty`, `const Faculty&`, `Faculty&`, `const Faculty*`  or `Faculty*`.

**Edit**: If the method creates `Faculties` and stores them in a private `std::set<Faculty>`, then an appropriate return value would be `const Faculty&`:

```
class University {
 public:
  const Faculty& createFaculty(args);
};
```

Then the caller can either take a reference, or make a copy:

```
const Faculty& f0 = uni1.createFaculty("hello"); // take reference
Faculty f1 = uni1.createFaculty("hi"); // make copy
```

Comment: It returns nothing...  do I have to make it to return something for what I want to do to work?

Comment: @user1455380 Yes, you do, it depends on how the Faculties are created and stored. Could you add some details concerning that? I have added some examples to my answer, but I had to make some assumptions.

Comment: @user1455380 if the answer is OK with you then you can accept it, then people know you consider the question answered.

Comment: Re the edit: if the `Faculty` are stored in a `std::set<Faculty>`, then you can't return a `Faculty&`.  You can't modify objects in a `std::set`.

Answer (score -1):

If your method `createFaculty` returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated Faculty object, just do:

```
Faculty* fac1 = uni1.createFaculty("Faculty 1");
```

so you can reference the new Faculty through fac1.

Comment: @DeadMG Wouldn't that depend on the implementation of createFaculty? Forgive me for my inexperience, but I though factory object did not keep ownership of the objects they create...